# Android set Chronometer format HH:MM:SS in notification

Tags: android, notifications, formatting, chronometer, android-remoteview

I want to display my notification with Chronometer with format HH:MM:SS, but the problem the format of Chronometer diplayed with H:MM:SS
For example 1:12:35, i want to see 01:12:35
Example code:
`remoteViews.setChronometer(R.id.myChronometer, ellapssedTime, null, true)